# From which layer we can apply Iwasawa's class number formula in Z_p extension?

Tags: nt.number-theory, iwasawa-theory

Let $K$ be a number field.   Let $K_\infty/K$ be a $\mathbb{Z}_p$ extension. Iwasawa proved that there are four integers $n_0,\mu,\lambda,\nu \geq 0$ such that for any $n\geq n_0$,  $$\mathrm{ord}_p(h_n)=\mu p^n+\lambda n + \nu,$$

where $h_n$ is the class number of the $n$-th layer field $K_n$ (so $K_0=K$).

My question is what do we know about $n_0$?  If we know how to compute $n_0$, then we can compute $\mu,\lambda,\nu$ in  finite steps, at least theoretically.

It is difficult for me to deduce an explicit formula for $n_0$ due to the pseudo-isomorphism.

One may wonder that does the integer $r_0$ such that $K_\infty/K_{r_0}$ is totally ramified at every ramified prime work? This is wrong. One can find   many examples in Schoof-Kraft's paper [Computing Iwasawa modules for real quadratic number fields], $K_\infty/K_0$ is totally ramified at every ramified prime, but $n_0> 0$.